# ConTeXt: change distance between inmargin bullets and text in bulleted list

Tags: spacing, lists, context, itemize

Can some kind soul show me how to specify the amount of horizontal space between list symbols (bullets, numbers, etc.) and item text in ConTeXt?

Specifically, I'm trying to create a bulleted list in ConTeXt with the bullets in the margins, which I've done, as reproduced in the example below. But I'd like to change the horizontal space between the bullets and the item text (specifically, I'd like to make it smaller). I've pored over the [setupitemgroup documentation page](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupitemgroup), and have tried setting `margin`, `leftmargin`, `distance`, and `textdistance`, but none of these seem to do what I'm looking for. I'd be grateful for any help you can provide.

```
\defineitemgroup[MyItems]
\setupitemgroup[MyItems][each][packed,inmargin][before={\bgroup},after={\egroup}]

\setupindenting[no]

\starttext

\|← left margin

\startMyItems
\item I like how my bullet is in the margin
\item but I wish it were just a little closer
\stopMyItems

\stoptext
```

[image: output of example code]

Comment: \labelsep is the length used.  Note, the bullet will move to the right unless you also change \itemindent (default =  0pt, and is reset each itemize).

Comment: @John, correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think \labelsep exists in ConTeXt.

Comment: Beats the heck out of me.  I have no idea what ConTeXt is.

Comment: ConTeXt is a document processing system built on top of Donald Knuth's TeX. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConTeXt; http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Main_Page.

Comment: To have the text of your `itemgroup` aligned with the border of the textblock you can set a negative value for the `margin` key, which has to be the same value as `width` because it is used for the indentation. The distance between the bullet and the text can be controlled with the `distance` key. The complete setup for this is `\setupitemgroup[MyItems][each][packed][width=5mm,margin=-5mm,distance=3mm,itemalign=flushright]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that is happening, add `\showframed` before `\starttext`, which shows:

[image]

So, the distance is equal to the distance between the left margin and text box, which is controlled by `leftmargindistance` key to `\setuplayout`. So, if you add:

```
\setuplayout[leftmargindistance=0.25ex]
```

you get

[image]

**Edit** Up on replying to a comment by Manuel, if occurred to me that perhaps you just want bullets that protrude to the left and are not necessarily in the margin. In that case, you can use:

```
\setupitemgroup[MyItems][each][packed][margin=-1em, width=1em]
```

Note that in this case, the bullet is not placed  in the margin.

[image]

Comment: But it seems rather bad to customize the layout to change that rather than an `itemgroup` parameter.

Comment: @Manuel is it because `\setuplayout` affects the effects of the whole document? I would have just `\advance\leftskip` `\item` by a value, and then lean over and `kern` it back.

Comment: @Manuel: The idea is that `inmargin` places the bullet in the ... well ... the margin. If you just want a negative left kern, you can use `\startitemize[margin=-2em, width=2em]`, etc. See my updated answer

Comment: @Aditya Wonderful explanation.